# A collocation meaning "one has anger"

Tags: translation, collocation

In the sentence "[...] once anger **prevails our consciousness** we should immediately distract ourselves to avoid its subsequent effects.", I have directly translated from Turkish, but I was told that there is not such an idiom in English(I mean **to prevail consciousness**). I guess you can easily infer what I want to convey by that idiom, how do I correct it?

Comment: How about *becomes apparent*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the metaphorical expression **flood one's consciousness**, not all that common but quite acceptable.

An example from [Cynicism and the Evolution of the American Dream, by Wilber W. Caldwell](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=UbKxJ_8qnqcC&pg=PT124&lpg=PT124&dq=%22floods+our+consciousness%22&source=bl&ots=f0VFnTrh6d&sig=GOMsgcet-dd0owUtgQHnLw-gkjk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CC8Q6AEwBWoVChMIp6iS88yAyQIVyNsOCh1NZg5D#v=onepage&q=%22floods%20our%20consciousness%22&f=false):

> The fourth way in which the American media creates and stimulates
>   widespread cynicism has to do with the way the media floods our
>   consciousness.

An example having a more obviously non-sentient subject, from [Libuvim](http://www.jerusalem-korczak-home.com/mona/sh2e.html), is:

> When the waves of the ocean of our life flood our consciousness ...

but this is getting rather gushy.

Dictionaries give different senses that point to the 'deluge' metaphor here; [RHK Webster's](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/flood) gives perhaps the closest sense:

> **flood** vt (9) to overwhelm with an abundance of something

If you're happy with a less word-for-word paraphrase,

> Anger surged through him
>
> He clenched his fists as the anger coursed through him

are more idiomatic (ie used more often).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your phrase is that *prevail* is an intransitive verb, so you need to use a preposition:

> [...] once anger prevails **in** our consciousness, [...]

which means that anger is the prevalent, most active component of our consciousness; or maybe

> [...] once anger prevails **over** our consciousness, [...]

which treats anger as an opposite to our consciousness, implying you can be so angry as to become unconscious.

Comment: I guess "to prevail" has more than meaning than I want. It is a bit strong. Is there any other choice?

Comment: Sure. _overtakes, takes over, gets hold of, invades, enters, possesses, occupies, is in, influences, affects, disorders, inflames, fills_ .... [one's mind]

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing either Turkish or the original text, I would say *anger dominates* one's consciousness.